# A project whereby to choose between wi-fi and bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, wifi

Im doing a research about connectivity. 
But Im still wondering what the costs are for implementing a bluetooth chip or wifi module in a device that will allow me to connect to the iPhone. Does somebody here know something about these costs?

A website with these modules is also sufficient.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

They're both relatively cheap. However, bluetooth is *very* limited when it comes to connectivity due to the half-ass job Apple did in implementing the required protocols to do something constructive with it. Wifi is limited because you have to establish some sort of AdHoc network (unless you have a wireless router in between), but after that you are basically limitless (though you have to do a lot of manual labor when it comes to implementing something useful.)

Comment: f your willing to join the MFI program then bluetooth isnt limited :)

Also have BTLE now which isnt limited either.

Comment: the same goes for jail-breaking the device, I didn't take all options into account with my answer (which didn't even really address the question), but out of the box Wifi still wins over Bluetooth on several important points.

Comment: I know that the iphone supports these bluetooth profiles:

• Phone Book Access Profile (PBAP)
• Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP)
• Audio/Video Remote Control Profile (AVRCP)
• Personal Area Network Profile (PAN) 
• Human Interface Device Profile (HID)
• Hands-Free Profile (HFP)

If I want to use bluetooth, shouldn I have bluetooth with the HFP protocol in it to communicatie to each other? 

I have also read somewhere that I need to have a licensed bluetooth module from appl before I can use it. True? And for wifi I dont care if I have to connect it to a network.

Comment: btw This MFI program, what will this affect to my bluetooth abilities? Do I also join this program if I need my app to run in the background because it needs to be connected to an iPhone accessory?